# Is there a clean, simple way to dynamically add dataframe columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

The MWE code below reads the elements in the `series_OS` object and adds dataframe columns using the count and names of elements in that `series_OS` object. It works as intended, including when reducing and increasing the number of elements in `series_OS`, but is there a cleaner way to do this in R? Would a `lapply()` function help?

I'm trying to keep this example chained in a series of dplyr `mutate()` statements because all the calculations in the full code this example derives are similarly chained together in a series of dplyr `mutate()` statements.

Code:

```
library(dplyr)

series_OS <- function() {c("Series_One", "Series_Two", "Series_Three")}

df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c(4, 5, 6)) %>%
  mutate(C = A * B) %>%
  { 
    series_names <- series_OS()
    for (name in series_names) {
      name_cleaned <- gsub("_", " ", name)
      . <- mutate(., !!paste0(name_cleaned, " date") := C - A)
    }
    .
  }

df
```

Comment: why use `for loop` with `mutate`? Use `mutate` and `across`. Note that the aim of tidyverse is to efficiently perform MapReduce. Consider avoiding for loops unless you are doing some hefty simulations. Also note that the cleaned named should be in snakecase format whereby they contain underscores rather than spaces. ie `janitor::clean_names` function should do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively you can define all the transformations in a list and then apply them by splicing them into mutate

```
transforms <- series_OS() %>% 
  gsub("_", " ", .) %>% 
  paste("date") %>% 
  setNames(replicate(3, expr(C-A)), .)
  
data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c(4, 5, 6)) %>%
  mutate(C = A * B) %>%
  mutate(!!!transforms)
```

Comment: In order to make this dynamic as the object generated by `series_OS()` can change, I changed the `setNames(...)` line of your code to `setNames(replicate(length(series_OS()), expr(C-A)), .)`

Answer (score 3):

another way could be:

```
data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c(4, 5, 6))%>%
   c(as.list(setNames(rep(NA, length(series_OS)), series_OS)))%>%
   as_tibble() %>%
   mutate(C = A * B, across(all_of(series_OS), ~C - A), .after = 'B') %>%
   rename_with(~str_c(str_replace(.x, '_', ' '), ' date'), all_of(series_OS))

#>   A B  C Series One date Series Two date Series Three date
#> 1 1 4  4               3               3                 3
#> 2 2 5 10               8               8                 8
#> 3 3 6 18              15              15                15
```

---

If you can separate the codes, ie no need to strictly chain the mutation:

```r
series_OS <- c("Series_One", "Series_Two", "Series_Three")


df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c(4, 5, 6))
df[series_OS] <- NA

df %>%
  mutate(C = A * B, across(all_of(series_OS), ~C - A), .after = 'B')%>%
  rename_with(~str_c(str_replace(.x, '_', ' '), ' date'), all_of(series_OS))
#>   A B  C Series One date Series Two date Series Three date
#> 1 1 4  4               3               3                 3
#> 2 2 5 10               8               8                 8
#> 3 3 6 18              15              15                15
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Note that in this example, you can change the names prior to adding them to the dataframe.

Comment: Works great! In order for this to work, since `series_OS()` in my OP is a function, in your code I had to change all references to `series_OS` fron `series_OS` to `series_OS()`.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario `purrr::reduce()` is useful. My solution is not a single
chain of piped commands, I am unsure if that is a helpful requirement to have.

```r
library(tidyverse)

series_names <- 
  c("Series_One", "Series_Two", "Series_Three") |> 
  str_replace("_", " ")

df <- 
  data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c(4, 5, 6)) |> 
  mutate(C = A * B)

reduce(c(list(df), series_names),
       \(x, y) x |> 
         mutate(!!paste0(y, " date") := C - A))
#>   A B  C Series One date Series Two date Series Three date
#> 1 1 4  4               3               3                 3
#> 2 2 5 10               8               8                 8
#> 3 3 6 18              15              15                15
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution which given `series_OS` and the input, `df0`, forms the names, `nms`, and then iterates over each one computing a `C-A` column and finally cbinds that to the input giving the final data frame.  Note that `data` and `expr` are `with` argument names.

```
# input
df0 <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c(4, 5, 6)) |> transform(C = A * B) 

nms <- paste(chartr("_", " ", series_OS()), "date")
cbind(df0, sapply(nms, with, data = df0, expr = C - A))
```

giving

```
  A B  C Series One date Series Two date Series Three date
1 1 4  4               3               3                 3
2 2 5 10               8               8                 8
3 3 6 18              15              15                15
```